# Can an Azure hosted Logic App connect to an on-premise Azure DevOps Server (formerly known as Team Foundation Server)

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to set up a webhook via Logic Apps to Azure DevOps Server (TFS). The idea is to automate a work item (bug) creation in our team backlog triggered by [Azure Monitor Metric alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-overview).

I have a gut feeling that this might be a dead end as we host our TFS on premise.

Can't seem to find any TFS connector on the [official list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/)

There is an Azure DevOps [conector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/) but seems like it is for Azure DevOps (cloud hosted).

How about deploying the Logic Apps within our Azure Vnet? That is the usual option for any cloud hosted service reach our on premise servers. Is it possible?

Does anyone have experience with something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the [MS On-Premises Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) installed on an on-premises machine on the same LAN where the on-premises DevOps (TFS) is. Then you create a [custom Logic App Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-logic-apps-connector) and connect to DevOps (TFS) through its [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). I didn't do it yet, but I used some very similar architecture to tackle various Logic Apps connections to on-premises systems (using both REST and SOAP protocols). I believe it's a simpler and more robust solution than relying on Azure's Vnet and using a Logic App connector that is not intended to be used with on-premises DevOps (TFS) - AFAICT. The REST API path for both services (cloud and on-premises) are different, so the Vnet approach may not work as expected.

Comment: Hi @vinicius, thanks for the nice workaround! Unfortunately I am still awaiting IT Ops for my first request based on the previous answer. I might as well freak them out and request your recommendation as well to speed things up :)

Answer (score 1):

How about deploying the Logic Apps within our Azure Vnet? we can do that by using integration service environment - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment

Let me know if you were looking for something else

Comment: Thanks for the helpful pointer, it looks very promising! I'll send a request to IT and see. Will get back to you and mark it as an answer if it is working out.

Comment: Sure, feel free to reach out for any questions regarding ISE.

Comment: @ystvan Not get your latest information, is Haris Abdulkareem's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @hugh-lin-msft it certainly led me to initiate some actions :) I am awaiting my request to be prioritized in IT Infrastructure team's backlog. As soon as the ISE Logic Apps are deployed and I am able to set up the webhooks I mark it as an answer.